# Getting instance of RoleManager in ASP.NET Core 8 new core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am experimenting with the new identity infrastructure in an ASP.NET web API app (as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

At startup, once `WebApplication` has been built and before running it, I would like to get instances of `UserManager<AppUser>` (where `AppUser` is just a class derived from `IdentityUser`) and `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` so that I can seed some preset user accounts.

AFAIK, the proper way of seeding data at startup is creating an extension method for `IHost` and call it in my `Program.cs` `Main` function, before running the app, e.g.:

```cs
public static async Task<IHost> SeedAsync(this IHost host)
{
  using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
  IServiceProvider serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;

  // ... use services like UserManager and RoleManager to seed user accounts ...
}
```

Anyway, it seems that while `UserManager` was registered as expected, there is no available service for `RoleManager`: when trying to get it I get an exception "'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered.'".

Here is a sample repro procedure:

(1) create a new ASP.NET Core 8 Web API app. No identity selected.

(2) add packages:

- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`

(3) add `AppUser.cs` and `AppDbContext.cs`, and change `Program.cs` as follows:

```cs
// AppUser.cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
}

// AppDbContext.cs
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) :
        base(options)
    { }
}

// Program.cs
public static class Program
{
    private static void ConfigureAuthServices(IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
            options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test"));

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<AppUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        // auth
        ConfigureAuthServices(services, configuration);

        // API controllers
        services.AddControllers();

        // Swagger/OpenAPI (https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle)
        services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();

        // database initializer
        services.AddScoped(sp =>
        {
            return new AppDatabaseInitializer(
                sp.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>(),
                sp.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>(),
                configuration,
                sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<AppDatabaseInitializer>>());
        });
    }

    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);

        WebApplication app = builder.Build();
        app.MapGroup("/account").MapIdentityApi<AppUser>();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();

        // testing DI for services
        using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            // this works
            var um = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            // ==> THIS THROWS
            var rm = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        }

        // here I would call await app.SeedAsync(); using my extension method
        // for IHost, using an AppDatabaseInitializer service requiring UserManager
        // and RoleManager via DI. Yet, it would fail just like the above code.

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

If you now run, you will see that it throws when trying to get `RoleManager` (while it succeeds in getting `UserManager`). How am I supposed to configure this V8 `Identity` system so that `RoleManager` gets configured properly for DI?

Comment: While adding `services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<AppUser>()` registers the UserManager service through a call to `services.AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>`, it doesn't automatically register the RoleManager service. You should include `.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityRole>();` Or `.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>();`  after `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()`.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway unless I'm missing some package there does not seem to be such extension method defined: `AddDefaultIdentity` does not compile. At the same location I tried with `AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` but this throws earlier at `builder.Build()` with "Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]".

Comment: how did you added identity within your application?

Comment: This is a dummy repro project, so the whole code is in my post. If you create a new ASPNET Core 8 app and follow the same steps, you should get to the same issue.

Comment: Hello, did you able to resolve the issue? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Comment: Thank you, I did not find a workaround yet, should I find one I'll post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` before the `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>` like this:

```
services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<AppUser>()
   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

Now you will be able to successfully inject the `RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager` in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Hope that documentation will get better here...

Comment: Yep! Can confirm, on .NET 8, using Autofac for DI, had the same issue and making sure `AddRoles` is called before `AddEntityFrameworkStores` fixes the issue - might be captured in the docs somewhere, but if it is I missed it too. Wanted to throw in the Autofac connection here, as it was an app config issue, not an issue with DI setup (Exception will come straight from Autofac, though)